# Facing NoClassDefFoundError in CoroutineScheduler

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am seeing some background crashes on my crashlytics dashboard.

```
CoroutineScheduler.java line 848
kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.doPark

Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
sun.misc.Unsafe.park (Unsafe.java)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos (LockSupport.java:353)
kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.doPark (CoroutineScheduler.java:848)
kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.cpuWorkerIdle (CoroutineScheduler.java:821)
kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run (CoroutineScheduler.java:727)
```

Kotlin version: **1.4.10**

Comment: Does it something have to do with multidex . have you tried to enable it ?

Comment: yes multidex is enabled